# Google Analytics Goal Tracking for Sub-Domains?

Tags: google, google-analytics

I am trying to track goals in Google Analytics for a website that has the goal URL on a sub-domain. The main domain for example is: domain.com and the sub-domain is my.domain.com. I have Google Analytics configured to track domains and all sub-domains and I've eve set up an advanced filter so I can see traffic to my sub-domains in Analytics.

However, in goal tracking, you're supposed to put in the website URL after the front (so if it were domain.com/conversions/ you'd put in just /conversions/). However, since for me it would be my.domain.com/conversions/, how would I input that URL into Analytics to track?

Would Analytics automatically determine the URL to be on the sub-domain?

Comment: Do you have the same URL path on both the main domain and the subdomain and need to distinguish between them?   If the URL path is only on the subdomain, then you shouldn't have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

With your settings Google Analytics will track as conversion visits to the page`http://subdomain.domain.net/conversions/` or `http://domain.net/conversions/`. Just add the URL `/conversions/` as the goal.